# How to apply correctly $limit and $skip in subfields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I'm starting with mongodb and I'm finding many difficulties with the following scheme.

```
{
    "_id" : "AAA",
 "events" : [ 
        {
            "event" : "001",
            "time" : 1456823333
        }, 
        {
            "event" : "002",
            "time" : 1456828888
        }, 
        {
            "event" : "003",
            "time" : 1456825555
        },...
        ]
}
```

I want to get the **events sorted by date and apply limit and skip.**
I'm using the following query:

```
$op = array(
    array('$match' => array('_id' => $userId)),
    array('$unwind' => '$events'),
    array('$sort' => array('events.time' => -1)),
    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$_id', 
                            'events' => array('$push' => '$events')))
    //,array('$project' => array('_id' => 1, 'events' => array('$events', 0, 3)))
    //,array('$limit' => 4)
    //,array('$skip' => 3)
);  
$result= Mongo->aggregate('mycollection', $op);
```

I have tried everything to filter **$project or $limit and $skip** but none of it works.

**How should I apply the limit and skyp conditions in events?**

If I do not apply the conditions of "limit" above the result is ordered correctly.
Result:

```
{ "waitedMS":0,
  "result":[
            {
            "_id":"AAA",
            "events":[
            {
                "event":"002",
                "time":1456828888,
            },
            {
                "event":"003",
                "time":1456825555,
            },
            {
                "event":"001",
                "time":1456823333,
            },...
            }
            ],
    "ok":1
}
```

**Order correctly but I can not limit the number of results for paging.**

Comment: The line `array('$sort' => array('events.t' => -1))`, isn't that supposed to be `array('$sort' => array('events.time' => -1))`?

Comment: @chridam No, it was a mistake. Fixed problem description but not the problem. Order correctly but I can not limit the number of results for paging.

Comment: Basically you want to "page" the array contents rather than the documents, right? Which MongoDB server version are you using? Anything less than 3.2 will make this quite difficult, but with 3.2 it's quite simple. Alternately for lesser versions, is there any reason why the array elements cannot be sorted by "time" as stored within the document permanently? Or indeed can the items just be appended directly in order (even if reversed)? If those are possible, then it's quite simple for other versions, and without an `.aggregate()` operation.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm using MongoDB 1.6.12 with PHP 5.6.17.

The connections are entered into the document without specific order.
And I tried using "find / findOne" and "sort" but not ordered when I do a query.

I can order through the following comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635755/sort-subfields-with-unknown-parent/35641795#35641795

Comment: The basic question I was asking of you is if the actual "skip" and "limit" you want to apply meant to "page" the array entries as opposed to the documents. So only get parts of the array in each request. That sort of looks like what you are trying, but I want to make sure. That's usually why we leave comments. So you can make things clearer than they are presently represented in your question. Makes a big difference between a right and wrong solution. And the reason why you presently remain unanswered.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I apologize I have difficulties with the language. 

In the array of connections I can have more than 1,000 items.
I want to show the content on a Web page by page.
For example 100 items per page.
To get it I need to use $ limit and $ skip.

In SQL it would be something like this: SELECT * FROM connections LIMIT 100,0

Comment: What I keep asking you is do you want array content like this `["100","200","300","400"]` to just come out as `["100","200"]` on one "page" and `["300","400"]` on another page?  Or do you just want **all** array entries and not split them up? That seems to be what you are asking since otherwise there seems nothing wrong with your current process. If language is a problem, then show sample results.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Example:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_limit_record.htm

I want to do a query that returns only the 50 most recent events.
Then, do it again, make another query requesting 50 events from the last requested.

If my array contains 150 events I would make 3 queries.

Comment: Yay. That only took all those times to ask the same thing before you actually confirmed it, sort of. So this is still per document? as in the "events" array in each document is only 50 items, or do you just want the top 50 events regardless of which document they are in? Also MongoDB version means "server version" and not the PHP driver version. Valid responses would be 2.4.x, 2.6.x, 3.0.x or 3.2.x. So which one of those as well? As mentioned earlier, it makes a difference regardling the complexity and process to do this.